# Is there a way to increment the iterator if an 'if' condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm solving [this HackerRank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-binary-string/problem):

> Alice has a binary string. She thinks a binary string is beautiful if and only if it doesn't contain the substring '010'.
>
> In one step, Alice can change a `0` to a `1` or vice versa. Count and print the minimum number of steps needed to make Alice see the string as beautiful.

So basically count the number of '010' occurrences in the string 'b' passed to the function.

I want to increment `i` by 2 once the `if` statement is true so that I don't include overlapping `'010'` strings in my `count`.

And I do realize that I can just use the count method but I wanna know why my code isn't working the way I want to it to.

```
def beautifulBinaryString(b):
    count = 0 
    for i in range(len(b)-2):
        if b[i:i+3]=='010':    
            count+=1                
            i+=2
    return count
```

Input: `0101010`

Expected Output: `2`

Output I get w/ this code: `3`

Comment: Use a `while` loop. In `for` loop, the looping variable does not affect even if it's value is changed within.

Comment: `for` in python is different from `for` in C/C++. It is in iterator over an `iterable` (a collection). So you can't skip an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it using a for loop, you can add a delta variable to keep track of the number of positions that you have to jump over the current i value.

```
def beautifulBinaryString(b):
    count = 0
    delta = 0
    for i in range(len(b)-2):
        try:
            if b[i+delta:i+delta+3]=='010':    
                count+=1                
                delta=delta+2    
        except IndexError:
            break
    return count
```

Answer (score 3):

You are counting *overlapping* sequences. For your input `0101010` you find `010` three times, but the middle `010` overlaps with the outer two `010` sequences:

```
0101010
--- ---
  ---
```

You can't increment `i` in a `for` loop, because the `for` loop construct *sets* `i` at the top. Giving `i` a different value inside the loop body doesn't change this.

Don't use a `for` loop; you could use a `while` loop:

```
def beautifulBinaryString(b):
    count = 0 
    i = 0
    while i < len(b) - 2:
        if b[i:i+3]=='010':    
            count += 1
            i += 2
        i += 1
    return count
```

A simpler solution is to just use `b.count("010")`, as you stated.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to count the occurrences; as soon as you find one occurrence, the string is "ugly". If you never find one, it's beautiful.

```
def is_beautiful(b):
    for i in range(len(b) - 2):
        if b[i:i+3] == '010':
            return False
    return True
```

You can also avoid the slicing by simply keeping track of whether you've *started* to see `010`:

```
seen_0 = False
seen_01 = False

for c in b:
    if seen_01 and c == '0':
        return False
    elif seen_1 and c == '1':
        seen_01 = True
    elif c == '0':
        seen_0 = True
    else:
        # c == 1, but it doesn't follow a 0
        seen_0 = False
        seen_01 = False
return True
```

Comment: No, the [actual challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-binary-string/problem) requires a count. Even if a True or False answer sufficed, then `return '010' in b` would have been much better.

Comment: Not that the OP explained the problem very well, they only quoted a small part of the challenge explanation.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, the while loop and using a delta variable answers really helped. Appreciate the quick response and thanks again.